# When writing block of code with php, php $variables on the page are ignored. Solution, anyone?

Tags: php, printf

I'm trying to embed a variable in a block of code that I'm writing with php into a text area so it can be easily selected and copied to another web site.  In production, the variables will be pulled from SESSION variables, but for you to be able to try this if you want by pasting it onto a page, I've hard wired the variable values.

The problem is that the php function is not picking up the variables.  I've tried it with SESSION variables that exist before the page is written --no go.  I've also tried loading variables into a form on the page and getting them through $_POST...no go.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?php session_start();
$fkey ="46"; 
$bleft = "0.86543";
$bpos = "tp";
$bcolor = "#eb9494";
$blabel = "CALL US";
echo "fkey:  " . $fkey . "<br/>" ; 
echo "bleft:  " .$bleft . "<br/>" ;
echo "bpos:  " .$bpos . "<br/>" ; 
echo "bcolor:  " .$bcolor . "<br/>" ; 
echo "blabel:  " .$blabel . "<br/>" ; 


      $updateGoTo = null;
  switch ($thepos) {
    case "tp":
  $updateGoTo = "slideouttesttopDATA.php";
  build_HTMLtp();
  break;    
case "bt":
         $updateGoTo ="slideouttestbtmDATA.php";
      build_HTMLbt();
      break; 
     case "lt":
           $updateGoTo = "slideouttestltDATA.php";
        build_HTMLlt();
  break; 
case "rt":
       $updateGoTo = "slideouttestrtDATA.php";
        build_HTMLrt();
  break; 
   }

  ?>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="myform" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

<?php 

function build_HTMLtp() {

    $myfield="&lt;style&gt;\n";
    //style blocks
    $myfield.=
"#slideouttop:{
    position:absolute;
    width:190px;height:187px;
    top:-238px;
    left:50%%;
}

.bizzopop,.bizzopopbtm{
    background:url(http://dev.bizzocall.com/images/bcpopupwtrans.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:auto;
    width:201px;
    overflow:visible;
    min-height:237px;
}
#clickmetop,#clickmebtm {
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    height:20px;
    width:80px;
}
#bcbuttontop,#bcbuttonbtm{
    background-color:#000000;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    left:0;
    height:30px;
    width:140px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.bcsquarebtntop,.bcsquarebtnbtm{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#000000;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    border:#ffFFFF;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border-width:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    left:6px;
    top:5px;
}

.innersquarebtn{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:3px;
    height:3px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:6px;
    position:relative;  
}

.btnlabeltxttop{
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline;
    overflow:visible;
    height:40px;
    width:100%%;
    text-align:left;
    text-indent:0;
    left:0px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#00FFFF;
    top:-23px;
    margin-left:32px;
}\n";
//special handling for variables
$myfield.=".bizzopop {background-color:" . $bcolor . ";}\n";

$myfield.=".btnlabeltxttop {color:". $bcolor .";}\n";

$myfield.="#slideouttop {
    left:". 100*($bleft) ."%%;
    display:". $tp .";
}

    #clickmetop {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    height:20px;
    width:80px;
    z-index:1000;
}
&lt;/style&gt;\n\n";
//now the html
$myfield.= "<div id=\"slideouttop\">
<div class=\"bizzopop\">
</div>
 <div id=\"clickmetop\">
<div id=\"bcbuttontop\">
  <div class=\"bcsquarebtntop\">
    <div class=\"innersquarebtn\"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class=\"btnlabeltxttop\">". $blabel ."</div>
</div>
</div>\n\n";
//jquery handlers
$myfield.="<script src=" . "\"http://" . "code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js\">        </script>\"\n
$(function() {\n
    $(\'#clickmetop\).toggle(function() {\n
        $(this).parent().animate({marginTop:\'187px\'}, {queue:false, duration:     500});\n
    }, function() {\n
        $(this).parent().animate({marginTop:\'0px\'}, {queue:false, duration:     500});\n
    });\n
});\n
</script>
";

  printf ($myfield);

}

?>

<textarea name="myfield" cols="100" rows="30"><?php build_HTMLtp();?>
</textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you talking about build_HTMLbt() not having access to a variable like $blabel?

Comment: So you're taking PHP, which is a language that can be seamlessly interspersed with HTML you wish to print, and you're then building strings of HTML (with many many escaped characters) in the code before... printing them out?

Comment: I'm writing out a piece of code that takes colors, labels, positioning information that has just been selected on a control panel. I use this to build this code snippet with CSS that has all the selected values. This is then copied and pasted into a client's site, giving them a customized slide out button without having to know squat about writing code.  Most web hosts do not allow you to include pages from other domains, and this has been a sticking point. This is only way I've been able to accomplish this without using Flash to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global variables are not accessible inside functions unless you use **global** or access them via the **$GLOBALS**-array.

Comment: "use global" means saying like `global $bleft;` at the top of the function that wants to use the global, in case that wasn't clear.

Comment: Right on! When your writing a function, just create the parameters  necessary for your function.

Comment: @I_miss_Steve_already: You should really stay away from globals, and instead pass args to the functions, or move to a more OO construct.